# Eloquent where condition based on a "belongs to" relationship

Tags: laravel, where-clause, eloquent, belongs-to

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Movie extends Eloquent
{
    public function director()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Director');
    }
}
```

Now I'd like fetch movies using a where condition that's based on a column from the directors table.

Is there a way to achieve this? Couldn't find any documentation on conditions based on a belongs to relationship.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You may try this (Check [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) on `Laravel` website):

```
$movies = Movie::whereHas('director', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'great');
})->get();
```

Also if you reverse the query like:

```
$directorsWithMovies = Director::with('movies')->where('name', 'great')->get();
// Access the movies collection
$movies = $directorsWithMovies->movies;
```

For this you need to declare a `hasmany` relationship in your `Director` model:

```
public function movies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Movie');
}
```

If you want to pass a variable into `function($q) { //$variable }` then

```
function($q) use ($variable) { //$variable }
```

Comment: The first one actually works! I didn't even try it since there is no whereHas relation, but a belongsTo. Still not sure why it would work and why there isn't a whereBelongsTo condition though.

Comment: Alpha, I want to pass a variable into `function($q) { //$variable }`. How can I do that? (Error log is "the variable is undefined").

Comment: `function($q) use ($variable) { //$variable }`

Comment: `$movies = Movie::whereHas('director', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'great');
})->get();`
**whereHas** didn't work for me instead the below code worked perfectly
`$deliveries = Delivery::with(array('order' => function($query)
{
     $query->where('orders.user_id', $customerID);
     $query->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC');
}))
    ->orderBy('date')
    ->get();`
Source : https://laravel.io/forum/08-21-2014-where-on-with-relation
Laravel 5.1

Comment: if i add in hasmany with where and pass param in movies then with movies where i can write params to pass them

Comment: Code sugar `whereRelation` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries 

`Movie::whereRelation('director', 'name', 'great');`

Answer (score 5):

#### whereBelongsTo()

For new versions of Laravel you can use `whereBelongsTo()`.

It will look something like this:

```
$director = Director::find(1);
$movies = Movie::whereBelongsTo($director);
```

More in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-belongs-to-relationships).

#### is()

For one-to-one relations `is()` can be used.

```
$director = Director::find(1);
$movie = Movie::find(1);

$movie->director()->is($director);
```

Comment: For me, I had to append ->get();, ie: ```whereBelongsTo($director)->get();```