# How to set where in relation Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use the following construction for joining tables: `with("attachments", "offers.publisher").`

```
public function publisher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id", "id");
    }
```

How to join `publisher` relation only when `offers.status = 1`?

In other words I need to use `publisher` by condition Where

I tried also this:

```
 $announcements = Announcement::whereHas('offers', function($q) {
            $q->with("publisher")->where('status', 1);
        })->get();
```

Comment: Or how to exclude `publisher` from result object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would to just have two definitions, `publishers` for all publishers, and `active_publishers` for those with `status = 1`:

```
public function publisher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id", "id");
}

public function active_publisher()
{
    return $this->publisher()->where('status', 1);
}
```

Use with `$object->active_publisher()->get();`

Comment: I got: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::active_publisher()`

Comment: Also I need join `publisher` if `offers.status=1`, but yoy wrote `user.status=1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is link that can help you:

Please check this:

[Eloquent where condition based on a "belongs to" relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970762/eloquent-where-condition-based-on-a-belongs-to-relationship)

Also you can do like this:

Suppose you have a post modal and each post has many comment. So can get the condition matching post comments by as following with where conditions

```
 public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

 App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo')->get();
```

Thanks